# Display fractions of pixels in UIKit for smooth slow motion

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a view which move down with a very slow constant speed.

```
var updater = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: Selector("loop"))

func loop() {
    view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y + 0.01)
}
```

`loop` is called 60 times in a second and move view 0.01 point down. 0.50 point is pixel on retina.

As far as I know UIKit only display full pixels. There is a problem for me, because view will only move on screen, when it's Y-coord is multiply of 0.50. But it is approximately 1.2 fps instead of expected 60. It looks bad, not smooth.

Is there any possibilities in UIKit to solve this?

Comment: Why are you using CADisplayLink for simple UIView animation?

Comment: What do you expect to see on screen when you only move the view 0.01 pixels?

Comment: @matt it may be considered as test example, in fact i have animation that can not be done by standard UIView animation engine

Comment: @rmaddy some transitional alpha pixels like in Photoshop or any other graphical editor

Comment: @user3537411 You might be able to get some mileage out of the `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` property. But in general since there is no such thing as illuminating a partial pixel the simple answer is "if you don't like the way it looks, don't do that".

Comment: @user3537411 See also this little section in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_points_and_pixels

Comment: @matt thanx a lot for allowsEdgeAntialiasing, it works! Seen your book before, very like it too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, since there is no such thing as illuminating a partial pixel, the simple answer is "if you don't like the way it looks, don't do that".

However, you *might* be able to get some mileage out of the `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` property of CALayer; I've no idea, because I've never tried it (it involves throwing a switch in your *Info.plist* as well, I believe, and it may introduce some drawing inefficiencies, so be careful).